# read-only php.ini file is preventing saving new configuration

Tags: php, ubuntu, pecl

I've installed ["PHP PECL EXTENSION/MODULE ON UBUNTU"](http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/04/how-to-install-a-php-pecl-extensionmodule-on-ubuntu/). At the end, I was asked to add some configuration lines in the a file called **php_ini** that can be found in this path:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

However, after making my changes, I can't save the file because the file is **read-only**.

What the appropriate action to save my changes. I don't really why the file is read-only, I don't know if there is some thing I need to do. I'm new in Ubuntu/php

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Use `sudo` to edit system files.

Comment: `sudo vim /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: @mario You should add this as an answer(possibly with a small explanation or mention to gksudo if he's planning on using a gui editor like gedit or knote), you're correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For accessing the system files you need root permission.So you would need to use `sudo` command.it would be like `sudo vim /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`(if u are using vim editor) as `user2075215` mentioned in comment.

Comment: I've tried the command, but I'm getting the error that there's not such command as vim. I'guess I must be missing vim. However I've got `gedit`. Isit still fine? Maybe I must get vim if I'll be using that often down the road.

Comment: You could try nano. I believe that is installed on Ubuntu systems by default. So... sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 2):

Use command:
"sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini"
It will open text editor, change your settings and save with ctrl+s and close the editor.
All changes will be saved.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am a beginner in Terminal, I used cd multiple times to get to the location of my `php.ini` file.
`cd etc
cd php
cd 7.0
.
.
.`

Then I did

`$ sudo xdg-open php.ini`

and the file popped up and I am able save edits now.